# find max square with black border

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

For a square matrix, each cell is either black (1) or white (0), trying to find the max sub-square whose border is black. Here is my code with Python 2.7, wondering if logically correct? And any performance improvements? Thanks.

My major ideas is, keep track of how many black nodes are on top (continuously) and on left (continuously), which is `left` and `top` matrix represents. Then, based on the `left` and `top` tracking, for any node, I will try to find minimal value of top and left continuous black node, then I will base the minimal value to see if a square could be formed.

```
A=[[1,1,0,0,0],
   [1,1,1,1,1],
   [0,0,1,0,1],
   [0,0,1,1,1],
   [0,0,0,0,0]]

top=[[0] * len(A[0]) for i in range(len(A))]
left=[[0] * len(A[0]) for i in range(len(A))]
result = 0

for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(A[0])):
        if A[i][j] == 1:
            top[i][j] = top[i-1][j] + 1 if i > 0 else 1
            left[i][j] = left[i][j-1] + 1 if j > 0 else 1
print top
print left

for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(A[0])):
        if A[i][j] == 1:
            top[i][j] = top[i-1][j] + 1 if i > 0 else 1
            left[i][j] = left[i][j-1] + 1 if j > 0 else 1

            x = min(top[i][j], left[i][j])
            if x > 1:
                y = min(left[i-x+1][j], top[i][j-x+1])
                result = max(result, y)

print result
```

**Edit 1**, fix an issue, which is pointed by j_random_hacker.

```
A = [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

A = [[0,1,1],
     [1,0,1],
     [1,1,1]]

top = [[0] * len(A[0]) for i in range(len(A))]
left = [[0] * len(A[0]) for i in range(len(A))]
result = 0

for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(A[0])):
        if A[i][j] == 1:
            top[i][j] = top[i - 1][j] + 1 if i > 0 else 1
            left[i][j] = left[i][j - 1] + 1 if j > 0 else 1
print top
print left

for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(A[0])):
        if A[i][j] == 1:
            top[i][j] = top[i - 1][j] + 1 if i > 0 else 1
            left[i][j] = left[i][j - 1] + 1 if j > 0 else 1

            x = min(top[i][j], left[i][j])
            if x > 1:
                y = min(left[i - x + 1][j], top[i][j - x + 1])
                if x == y:
                    result = max(result, y)

print result
```

**Edit 2**, address the issue by j_random_hacker.

```
A = [[0,1,0,0],
     [1,1,1,1],
     [0,1,0,1],
     [0,1,1,1]]

A = [[0,1,1],
     [1,0,1],
     [1,1,1]]

A = [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]


top = [[0] * len(A[0]) for i in range(len(A))]
left = [[0] * len(A[0]) for i in range(len(A))]
result = 0

for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(A[0])):
        if A[i][j] == 1:
            top[i][j] = top[i - 1][j] + 1 if i > 0 else 1
            left[i][j] = left[i][j - 1] + 1 if j > 0 else 1
print top
print left

for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(A[0])):
        if A[i][j] == 1:
            top[i][j] = top[i - 1][j] + 1 if i > 0 else 1
            left[i][j] = left[i][j - 1] + 1 if j > 0 else 1

            x = min(top[i][j], left[i][j])
            while x > 1:
                y = min(left[i - x + 1][j], top[i][j - x + 1])
                if x == y:
                    result = max(result, y)
                    break
                x -= 1

print result
```

**Edit 3**, new fix

```
A = [[0,1,0,0],
     [1,1,1,1],
     [0,1,0,1],
     [0,1,1,1]]

A = [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
     [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
     [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

A = [[0,1,1],
     [1,0,1],
     [1,1,1]]

top = [[0] * len(A[0]) for i in range(len(A))]
left = [[0] * len(A[0]) for i in range(len(A))]
result = 0

for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(A[0])):
        if A[i][j] == 1:
            top[i][j] = top[i - 1][j] + 1 if i > 0 else 1
            left[i][j] = left[i][j - 1] + 1 if j > 0 else 1
print top
print left

for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(A[0])):
        if A[i][j] == 1:
            top[i][j] = top[i - 1][j] + 1 if i > 0 else 1
            left[i][j] = left[i][j - 1] + 1 if j > 0 else 1

            x = min(top[i][j], left[i][j])
            while x > 1:
                y = min(left[i - x + 1][j], top[i][j - x + 1])
                if x <= y:
                    result = max(result, x)
                    break
                x -= 1

print result
```

Comment: @OhadEytan Nope. User does not appear to be convinced the code works. Also, if you think code is off-topic anywhere on the Stack Exchange network, close it because it's off-topic there. Not because it may or may not be on-topic somewhere else. There's a good reason Code Review is not listed as migration target.

Comment: @Mast I think that the OP will answer "yes" to [question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) _"To the best of my knowledge, does the code work as intended?"_  
Also, look [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251654/2069380) for the _"good reason"_ and in the comments there.

Comment: @OhadEytan I counter your link with [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311349/1014587). As for whether the OP will answer yes, OP should clarify whether it works. `Here is my code with Python 2.7, wondering if logically correct?` makes me wonder whether he verified the output he got.

Comment: I think it is better if you can put pseudo code or an explanation of general idea how you solve the problem.

Comment: @PhamTrung, thanks for the advice. I have updated the post with summary of ideas. Your advice of my code functionality issue or performance improvements are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't logically correct, as the following simple counterexample shows:

```
011
101
111
```

This array contains no bordered square, but your code reports that it contains a square of edge length 3.  You need either a third nested loop through *all* candidate square sizes down from `x` to 1 (making the solution O(n^3)-time) or, possibly, some more sophisticated data structure that enables an equivalent check to be performed faster.

**[EDIT to address updated algorithm]**

The new algorithm thinks there is no bordered square in either

```
0100
1111      1111
0101  or  0101
0111      0111
```

despite there being a 3x3 one in each.

Stop guessing at fixes and think about how to break down the set of *all possible* locations of bordered squares into sets that you can efficiently (or even not-so-efficiently) check.  As I tried to say at the top: For each possible bottom-right corner of a bordered square, your code is currently only checking *one* rectangle.  But many more rectangles could have (i, j) as a bottom-right corner -- where are the tests for them?

Comment: Thanks j_random_hacker for pointing out the issue, I am wondering what is wrong in my logic? I thought my code already check from right bottom, to left bottom, right top, then finally to left top.

Comment: BTW, I fixed an issue in my code, and please refer to Edit 1 part, I think it is doable in O(n^2) time without another loop. Appreciate for your further advice in advance.

Comment: Thanks j_random_hacker, for your input, my code output 0, I think it is the right value. You think should output 1? I test your left sample, since it requires to be a square.

Comment: And for your comments -- "But many more rectangles could have (i, j) as a bottom-right corner -- where are the tests for them", definitely agree. You can see I am using `x = min(top[i][j], left[i][j])`, you mean within `x`, I should check all possible squares other than check only one?

Comment: Hi j_random_hacker, I have fixed the issue by Edit 2 part of my post, if you could review and comment, it will be great. Thanks.

Comment: "for your input, my code output 0, I think it is the right value" -- no, 3 is the right value for both of my new examples.  If you no longer believe the correct answer is 0 (I guess you don't believe it anymore, since you talk about "fixing the issue" later), please delete it as it's confusing otherwise.

Comment: Your "Edit #2" code will *still* incorrectly report 0 for my new example input on the left (i.e., the first array you set `A` to in this code) -- please at least test on the examples I've already given before asking me to verify correctness.  Why do you think `x == y` must hold for there to be a square?

Comment: Thanks j_random_hacker, nice catch and I mis-read your example of 4*4 square, I fixed my issue and I post my code in Edit3 part. I think it has no bugs, and if you could help to review and confirm, it will be great. :)

Comment: Thanks j_random_hacker, appreciate for your patience. Then I vote your reply as answer. :)